# Does a receiver declared in the Manifest start the apps process and the Application class?

Tags: android, process, broadcastreceiver

In one of my apps I use a subclass of Application (MyApplication) and a BroadcastReceiver (MyBroadcastReceiver) that's added to the Manifest. The BroadcastReceiver registers the actions **android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED** and **android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED**.

These intents are fired when the APK is added to or replaced on a device. The app itself is not shown during the installation process so my question is: Will the Application subclass get started along with the app process?

Here's the code:

**Manifest:**

```
<application
    ...
    android:name=".MyApplication" >

    ...

    <receiver
        android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <data
                android:path="xxx.yyy.zzz"
                android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

**MyApplication:**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "onCreate");

        // ...
        }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        // ...

        super.onTerminate();
    }
}
```

**MyBroadcastReceiver:**

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String TAG = "xxx.yyy.zzz.MyBroadcastReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null && intent.getDataString() != null) {
            if (intent.getDataString().contains("xxx.yyy.zzz")) {
                if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)) {
                    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "onReceive(Package added)");

                    // ...
                } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED)) {
                    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "onReceive(Package replaced)");

                    // ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, your app will *not* receive these broadcasts upon it's own installation or removal.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. It seems to be true for ADDED but not for REPLACED. It's just a thought of mine because this text "Note that the newly installed package does not receive this broadcast" is only mention for ADDED - not for REPLACED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will the Application subclass get started along with the app process?

Yes. The `Application` object should be created before your `BroadcastReceiver` instance is created and called with `onReceive()`.